# Sequelize and WITH HOLD cursors

Tags: node.js, postgresql, cursor, sequelize.js

I'm trying to implement cursor pagination with postgresql and sequelize, I have tried with success creating a cursor WITH HOLD on a transaction and fetching data from it.

```
sequelize.transaction(function (t) {

    const query = "DECLARE my_cur CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT foo, bar FROM x " +
        "WHERE time=\'2016-09-16\'::date;"

    return sequelize.query(query, {transaction: t}).spread(function (results,metadata) {
        console.log("Cursor created!")
    });

}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result)
    console.log("Transaction commited")
    sequelize.query("FETCH NEXT FROM my_cur").spread(function (results,metadata) {
        console.log("Fetching from previously created cursor:")
        console.log(results)
        console.log(metadata)
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log("Failed to fetch from cursor")
        console.log(err)
    });
}).catch(function (err) {
    throw err
    console.log("Failed to create a cursor")
});
```

If I try fetching from the cursor in a different session I get:

```
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cur;
ERROR: <<my_cur>> doesn't exist.
```

Cursors even if declared WITH HOLD are destroyed after a session closes and aren't shared between sessions, my question is, how does sequelize handle sessions with postgreSQL, will I be able to FETCH from this cursor on a separate API call?

```
socket.on("fetch_next_page", function()){
   var cursor = socket.session.cursor
   var pageSize = 10
   sequelize.query("FETCH +"pageSize"+ FROM my_cur").spread(function (results,metadata) {
            console.log("Fetching from previously created cursor:")
            console.log(results)
            socket.emit("page",results)
            console.log(metadata)
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log("Failed to fetch from cursor")
            console.log(err)
        });
}
```

Comment: Since all you need is a shared session for the set of above queries, you can use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) for that instead. It easily executes single-connection queries, see [Tasks](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#tasks) and [Transactions](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#transactions).

Comment: Sadly I found out about this after making the bounty and made a (successfull) implementation using https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres, please post your comment as an answer so you can claim the bounty before it expires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to execute a sequence of queries within the same session is via a task or transaction as implemented within [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

See [Tasks](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#tasks) and [Transactions](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#transactions).

You would either promise-chain your queries, if they have a dependency between them, or execute them as a batch, if they don't.

And if you need to iterate N times inside the session, like calling `FETCH` till certain condition, you can also make use of method [sequence](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Task.html#.sequence).

Comment: Makes sense, notice that this meant bypassing sequelize completely to do the queries but this way ok

Comment: @JesusGomez I've updated the answer. If you intend to call `FETCH` till certain condition, use of method `sequence` inside task/transaction is the most beneficial ;)